# Doing a validation check on a AJAX post and returning the error message

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an AJAX post that does this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@MyWebSite.Url/myController/myView",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ myModel: myData }),
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    success: function () {
        alert('Success!');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error! ');
    }
})
```

My controller does the validation check but it is not correctly returning the error message.
This is what my controller looks like:

```
if (totalQty < part.QtyInItem) {
    //ModelState.AddModelError("", "My ERROR Message");
    //RedirectToAction("myControler", myModel);
    return this.Json(new { success = false, message = "My Error Message" });
}
```

When I tried adding an error to the model state it just returned "ERROR!" and not the error message I had associated with it. And when I try doing the this.JSON return it returns "success" to the view and not the error message.

How can I do this validation check for my AJAX post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add data object to your function.

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@MyWebSite.Url/myController/myView",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data:
                    JSON.stringify({ myModel: myData }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    traditional: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.message);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Error! ');
                    }
```

If you are still getting error, you should check your console for any server errors.

Comment: Why is it returning as ```success``` though? Shouldn't it be returning as error since I said in my code that ```success = false```?

Comment: Success means that server responded with data. You cannot set success this way. You can access it by checking data.success .